# Select all items in the Online Update of CLI Yast

Tags: opensuse, suse, yast

Is there an efficient way of selecting all items to be installed (mark +) in the Online Update window of command line Yast? Currently if there are a lot of (non-essential) updates available one has to mark each update separately by pressing enter. This can be annoying when there are hundreds of updates.

I am only looking for solutions involing the CLI version of Yast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use zypper update. It prompts you to update all.

Comment: So as far as Yast is concerned, that is not possible?